# If-statement in the MySQL stored procedure for selecting data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have the next SQL code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`new_procedure` (queryString VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT @tempValue = COUNT(*) FROM test.userdata_extended WHERE inn LIKE queryString;
    IF @tempValue > 0 SELECT * FROM test.userdata_extended WHERE inn LIKE queryString;
END $$
```

I'm putting the `COUNT*` result into `@tempValue` variable.
Then I'm trying to compare it for being greater than zero.

I'm getting error with the statement comparing process. MySQL reports me a `UNEXPECTED SELECT SYM` error. What does it mean?

Also this would be a check for another tables. I need IF-ELSE statements, because basing  on several query result my procedure must return the exact code error value (which could be different) for the my developed application to handle or giving the data, if all is fine.

How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot the `THEN` in your if statement. You need to add the `THEN`.

Like this:

```
IF @tempValue > 0 THEN ...your statement 
END IF;
```

You have also forgot to add the `END IF;` add this also.

[Reference site is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html).

Comment: you have forgot about `END IF;` please add a tiny info in yours answer :)

Comment: also, can you loot at the my comment at the second answer? I just don't want to make copies, thanks! it's about another style

Comment: @GeloVolro Thanks to remind. By the I have given the reference site also. but again thanks.

Comment: http://ideone.com/S7SGI2 May I ask you about smth more? I've done the code, but MySQL is returning not the ALL table data, but strange result: http://s24.postimg.org/dazpic2ht/Untitled.png can you help me, please? thanks! don't be angry, I'm a newbie to SQL procedures :)

Comment: @GeloVolro you need to recode the following line as `select COUNT(*) into @tempValue from` and declaire the variable above and then check.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `THEN` and `END IF;`

```
IF @tempValue > 0 THEN 
      SELECT * FROM test.userdata_extended WHERE inn LIKE queryString;
END IF;
```

Comment: Could it be doen with smth similar to: 

SELECT IF(@tempValue > 0, *, "null") FROM test.userdata_extended WHERE inn LIKE queryString;

?

Comment: What do you want to achieve, you need all 3 conditions in if?

Comment: yes, smth similar to that what you've meant, but now I think it's a bad idea, isn't it?